# Xcode 11.5 Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 when using .C source

Tags: c, objective-c, swift, ios13, arm64

I'm attempting to use some C code in a Swift project for iOS.

The C code comes with a makefile that will compile a static .a library for the x86_64 architecture. Obviously, to use this code in iOS we need arm64 compatibility.

I've tried a few different approaches including:

1. Throwing the C source and header files directly into the project, listing the C header in the bridging header.
2. Same as approach #1 but routing my C calls through an Objective-C intermediary.
3. Using Swift Package Manager to package up the C code into a framework I can drop into the project.

On approaches #1 and #2, Xcode is giving me code completion and syntax highlighting so I know the C headers are being picked up but at compile time I get error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
```

If I try to call a simple C function I wrote myself, everything works fine. So I'm wondering if there's something in the lower level C I'm trying to use that is incompatible with arm64 or if I may simply need to modify something in my Xcode build settings.

Comment: Are the symbols it complains about an exact match for what's in the C source or are they name-mangled in any way?  Do you see that the C sources are actually being compiled when you look at a build log in the Report Navigator?  Do the C sources contain any preprocessor directives for excluding code when compiling?

Comment: @PhillipMills No, the undefined symbol has an `_` prepended to the name of the function that is in the C source. I checked the build log and I do not see the C source files listed as compiled. I don't believe the C sources contain preprocessor exclude directives but I will double check. What would they look like?

Comment: Attempting to compile them sounds like a good first step.  You should be able to select them in the project and then mark them as part of your target in the File Inspector panel.  Or you can add them to the Compile Sources section of the Build Phases part of the target configuration view.

Comment: @PhillipMills Thank you, I just added the C files to compile sources, I thought they were already in there. The original missing symbol error is gone but now I have 6 other missing symbols. I guess I'm looking at a dependency nightmare now and I just need to keep plugging the holes till there are none left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was resolved by ensuring all files were listed in Compile Sources